# Wordpress PrettyPhoto Gallery from link

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, image-gallery

I want to have a link that opens a prettyphoto gallery. I am using Wordpress with the Visual Bakery plugin as an editor.

I found if I do this...

```
<a class="prettyphoto" href="https://paradisocommunities.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Heirloom-LegacyPointe32.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[rel-17-696085417]">Link Text or Image</a>
```

...it will show use the prettyphoto popup window but there will not be a gallery. You can see this work if you click the Inspire button on this page: https://paradisocommunities.com/model/the-heirloom/

Does anyone know how to make this link a gallery?

The shortcode for an image grid gallery in Visual Composer is:

```
[vc_gallery type="image_grid" images="1017,1016,1015,1014,1013,1012,1011,1010" img_size="full"]
```

Is it possible to use these numbers to make it a gallery or just the file names?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve that by adding one more attribute to the link.

```
rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"
```

This is from discussion on their official support forum:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/go-to-prev-and-next-photo-in-lightbox-view/#post-4528237

Comment: This doesn't help because it doesn't know what images to load (I think). I have tried it with this rel="prettyPhoto[rel-17-95584683]" which is a reference to a gallery I created on another page: https://paradisocommunities.com/the-heirloom-gallery/. The problem is that it doesn't know what images it wants me to load into PrettyPhoto, it just gives me the first one that is in the link.